# What is the use of this particular caching in UniswapV3's OracleTest.sol file?

Tags: solidity, uniswapv3

In [UniswapV3's OracleTest.sol file](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/main/contracts/test/OracleTest.sol), the function getGasCostOfObserve caches the storage variables to memory.

```
function getGasCostOfObserve(uint32[] calldata secondsAgos) external view returns (uint256) {
    (uint32 _time, int24 _tick, uint128 _liquidity, uint16 _index) = (time, tick, liquidity, index);
    uint256 gasBefore = gasleft();
    observations.observe(_time, secondsAgos, _tick, _index, _liquidity, cardinality);
    return gasBefore - gasleft();
}
```

As the storage variables are used just once, why is such a caching done?

Answer (score 1):

Because if they did not do that, gas would be used inside the range of where they are trying to measure gas for the sload. The purpose of this function seems to be to measure the gas of observations.observe, so if you put the storage variables directly into its parameters, gas would be used to convert the parameters from storage into calldata/memory, which does not seem to be a gas cost we want to observe.

I would assume when observations.observe is called in its main place, it does not have to do this conversion before executing its logic.

So, summed up, we cache them to make the gas measurement returned by this function accurate, even though it does not save gas overall with the specific logic in this function. We want the sloads gas cost to not be included in the gas measurement returned.

Comment: That concept makes sense. But the actual implementation of observe takes storage variables as parameters. Also, I couldn't understand the reason for cardinality being not cached while the other variables are.

Comment: So in its usage, it seems observe is just used for an external view function inside V3Pool, however the helper function inside observe, observeSingle, is called with memory arguments. They probably really care about the gas of that observeSingle function, since its called inside the updatePosition / swap functions, with cached memory vars in that case. There are 2 cases of it being called with cached variables and one case of it being called without cached vars. I assume the one case without is because that call is the only time that storage slot is used in that function.

Comment: As for why cardinality is not cached, I'm not really sure. Maybe its a mistake. It seems to be cached in the calls where the other vars are cached. I'm sure the test contracts on uniswap v3 have not had nearly has much scrutiny and review as the main onchain logical contracts, so maybe cardinality not being cached is actually just a mistake.